# Jekyll - exclude folder, but include subfolder

Tags: jekyll

I have a structure like:

```
folder/
folder/subfolder/
```

I want to exclude everything from folder/, except folder/subfolder/.

I there any way to do this with Jekyll? I tried a few combinations, but neither works, e.g.:

```
exclude: ["folder"]
include: ["folder/subfolder"]
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: You may want to weigh in here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4791

Comment: This has finally been merged and should be fixed, see [#4791](http://www.github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4791)

Answer (score 1):

As of Jekyll Version 4.X, it [now possible to include subfolders and exclude base folder](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/3-to-4/#exclusion-changes) just as OP did in the posting.